# Concatenation doesn't work

Tags: php

I created a database for all inquiries, the concatenation in the values doesn't work on my end. It shows blank on the database field but the primary id and the datetime is showing up.

```
$inputvalidate_inquiry="INSERT INTO inquire_list665 (inquireid, inquirename, inquiremail, inquiremsg, inquirewhn)
VALUES(inquireid, '".$valinp."', '".$valinp1."', '".$valinp2."', now())";
$sve_inq = mysql_query($inv_inq);
```

Please help ... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

concatenation if I've fields as `id` `name` `user_name` `email` `password` `date` you should keep the id `null` or blank. you can concatenate variable and string as `" '.$name.' "`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `work`.`user` (`id`, `name`, `user_name`, `email`, `password`, `date`) VALUES ('','$name','$user_name','$email','$password','NOW()');";
```